# How put grouping variable to columns in SQL/

Tags: sql

I have following dataset

[image]

and want to get this

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Which database are you using? The answer may vary.

Comment: @YvesPédron I am using Vertica

Comment: I am not familiar with Vertica, but the following post might be of help : https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/238733/how-do-i-pivot-in-vertica

Comment: I wrote for Vertica

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
select
time,[group],value
from yourTable    
group by time,[group],value
)
as table
pivot
(
sum([value])
for [group] in ([a],[b],[c])
) as p
order by time
```

This is the result

[image]

for Vertica,

```
SELECT time
     , SUM(value) FILTER (WHERE group =  a) a
     , SUM(value) FILTER (WHERE group =  b) b
     , SUM(value) FILTER (WHERE group =  c) c
  FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY time
```

Comment: it gives me an error ERROR: Syntax error at or near "(" [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=4856]

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Server, you can use a PIVOT, such as :

```
SELECT Time, [a],[b],[c]
FROM
  (
   SELECT time, [group],value
   FROM dataset) d
   PIVOT
   (
   SUM(value)
   FOR [group] IN ([a],[b],[c])
   ) AS pvt
```

You can try it on the following [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=258ce9d6fa551e2f3f98ca329b89bc6f).

Answer (score 1):

Changed the column names to not conflict with reserved words. You would have to put them into single quotes otherwise.

```
WITH
-- the input
indata(grp,tm,val) AS (
          SELECT 'a',1,44
UNION ALL SELECT 'a',2,22
UNION ALL SELECT 'a',3, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',1, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',2, 5
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',3, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',1, 7
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',2, 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',3, 9
)
SELECT tm
     , SUM(CASE grp WHEN 'a' THEN val END) AS a
     , SUM(CASE grp WHEN 'b' THEN val END) AS b
     , SUM(CASE grp WHEN 'c' THEN val END) AS c
FROM indata
GROUP BY tm
;
 tm | a  | b | c
----+----+---+---
  1 | 44 | 1 | 7
  2 | 22 | 5 | 8
  3 |  1 | 6 | 9
```